# good books that explained optimization using SA,Genetics and ... algorithm

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, operations-research

I don't know this is right place for asking this but I had no Other options 
In Operation Research Course My professor give us some lecture note about nonlinear optimization and some algorithm for solving them but I can't understand them.
I'll be appreciate if recommend me good resourced(book is preferred) for study nonlinear optimization and related algorithms

Comment: hello , numerical optimization nocedal and wright , is good . and have algorithm too